# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the value of `get_option()` function just before the line `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` in `wp-config.php` file and getting following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\WordPressSites\SvamGlobal\wp-config.php:106 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\WordPressSites\SvamGlobal\wp-load.php(37):
>   require_once() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WordPressSites\SvamGlobal\wp-blog-header.php(13):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WordPressSites\SvamGlobal\index.php(17):
>   require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\WordPressSites\SvamGlobal\wp-config.php on line 106

This is the code that I am trying in `wp-config.php` file.

```
$blogValue = get_option( 'blogs_creators', '' );
print_r($blogValue);
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

How can I get it solved?

**Updated:**

As **@MasivuyeCokile** suggested, I have changed the code as:

```
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

$blogValue = get_option( 'blogs_creators', '' );
print_r($blogValue);
define('BLOGS_CREATORS', $blogValue );
```

Now I am able to get the value of `get_option( 'blogs_creators', '' )` but the issue is in `functions.php` file. The defined contstant `BLOGS_CREATORS` is not available in `functions.php`.

That's why I was getting it before settings.

Hope It makes sense. :)

Comment: The setting file must load first it set's up the wordpress vars and all other wp files... `option.php` is loaded by the `wp-settings.php` file as well

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, Thanks I have updated my question, Please help me now.

Comment: Check on your functions file if the options file is included or not `print_r(get_included_files());` then see if the file will show if not then just include it `include_once('wp-includes\option.php');`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, Yes it's shown as included in `functions.php` file.

Comment: Then get option should work on your functions

Comment: unfortunately No, it's printed `BLOGS_CREATORS`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile, I am tring to get it at the bottom of the `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by defining constants in `functions.php` file as:

Used an action hook `after_setup_theme`

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'constants' );

function constants() {
  $blogValue = get_option( 'blogs_creators', '' );
  define('BLOGS_CREATORS', $blogValue );
}
```

Now the `BLOGS_CREATORS` is available everywhere as:

```
print_r(BLOGS_CREATORS);
```